# Confirm before exit the command-prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, trap

I am trying to have a confirmation message every time I type `exit` command in the command-prompt. To do this, I have tried to use `trap` in `.bashrc` file but it seem like trap is not a solution as it run the original command anyway. Is there a way I can have this?

Here is my bashrc script code which could not get the job done:

```
function _exit()        # Function to run upon exit of shell.
{
    read -p "${RED}Are you sure? " REPLY
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        echo -e "${RED}Bye${NC}"
        exit 0
    else
        #I do not know what to do here to not exit
        return
    fi  
}
trap _exit EXIT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the shell is `zsh` or `bash` (though not in `sh` mode), make `exit` a function. Functions have precedence over shell builtins (even special ones like `exit`) in `zsh` or `bash` (though not in POSIX shells). So just rename your function to `exit` and use `command exit` within the function instead. Otherwise you had endless recursion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Overload function `exit()` won't fit the `^D` scenario. So, let's talk about `trap`.

Your `else` clause should be some things that can either hold bash or ignore the exit signal. I don't know how to do that either.

But for now, alternatively, I think you can re-open bash.

If you replace your `else` clause with this:

```
echo
history -a
bash
```

And then if you cancel the exit on the prompt, a new bash will be re-opened, and it'll looks much like nothing happend, just like in the old one.

This approach does have a flaw, you will lose the variable assignments you typed in before, may be we can work on that. But if you're cool with this, this is it.

You can modifiy this code to fit your needs anyway.